# Serving cross-site content - JSONP, iframe or something else?

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm building an ad network. This entails 3rd party sites including my javascript, then replacing divs they specify with my content.

We need to dynamically determine which piece of content to serve into those divs, so this requires a cross-site call. AFAIK the popular ways to achieve this are JSONP and iFrame. What are the pros and cons of each approach? Particularly, I'm interested in:

- Browser compatibility
- End user performance
- Ad performance tracking
- Resilience to 3rd party site tampering (i.e. faking clicks)
- What existing ad networks use

If there are other technologies would like to learn about them also.

EDIT: After doing some research, another option seems to be an image tag that does a 302 redirect so the server can chose an image dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to implement CORS on yiur server, but that only works with modern browsers, so may not be a suitable option for you.